# R How to Label Means in ggboxplot() with 3 Variables and a 4-level Factor? (Attempt shown)

Tags: r, ggplot2

This attempt at labeling the means results in the middle value of each group getting a label.

```
ggboxplot(DataW, x = "Factor-r-Level", y = c("Var1","Var2","Var2"),  
merge = TRUE, palette = "jco", add="mean") +  
stat_summary(fun.y=mean, colour="darkred", geom="point", hape=18,  
size=3,show_guide = FALSE) + stat_summary(fun.y=mean, colour="red",  
geom="text", show_guide = FALSE, vjust=-0.7, aes( label=round(..y.., digits=1)))
```

[image]

The data is formatted:

```
> head(DataW)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  Factor-4-Level      Var1           Var2              Var3  
  <chr>              <dbl>          <dbl>             <dbl>
1 Level-1             7.75           8.08              8.82
2 Level-3             6.62           6                 5.36
3 Level-2             7.12           7.17              7.18
4 Level-3             7.5            7.83              7.73
5 Level-4             6.12           8                 7.45
6 Level-4             8.25           8.08              7
```

I would like to use ggboxplot(), and I would like the sets of three visually grouped together, as they are.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not quite enough data here to make a reproducible example, so here's a rough approximation of your data set:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(69)

DataW <- tibble(`Factor-4-Level` = paste0("Level-", sample(4, 200, TRUE)),
                 Var1 = rnorm(200, 7, 2), 
                 Var2 = rnorm(200, 7.5, 1.8),
                 Var3 = rnorm(200, 8, 2.1))

head(DataW)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>   `Factor-4-Level`  Var1  Var2  Var3
#>   <chr>            <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Level-4          11.4   6.27  6.76
#> 2 Level-1          10.2   6.91 11.0 
#> 3 Level-3           8.71  5.82  8.27
#> 4 Level-2           8.61  6.79  9.24
#> 5 Level-4           4.70  7.78  9.76
#> 6 Level-4           7.20  6.31  7.22
```

If you are insistent on using `ggboxplot`, you will need to map the text and points to the Var1, Var2, Var3 grouping variable so that you can position them correctly using `position_dodge`. Unfortunately `ggboxplot` doesn't allow you to specify this variable's name, but a bit of detective work reveals that the relevant grouping variable is somewhat confusingly called `.y.` inside the `ggplot` object produced by `ggboxplot`, so you can do:

```r
library(ggpubr)

ggboxplot(DataW, x = "Factor-4-Level", y = c("Var1", "Var2", "Var3"),  
          merge = TRUE, palette = "jco", add = "mean") +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "point", shape = 18, size = 3,
               aes(group = .y.), color = "darkred",
               position = position_dodge(width = 0.8)) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, colour = "red", 
               position = position_dodge(width = 0.8),
               geom = "text", vjust = -0.7, 
               aes(label = round(..y.., digits = 1), group = .y.))
```

[image]

Incidentally, it's actually very easy to get the same plot using `ggplot` itself if you want the ability to easily add custom aesthetic mappings:

```r
DataW %>% 
  pivot_longer(-1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(`Factor-4-Level`, value, color = name)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "point", shape = 18, size = 3,
               aes(group = name), color = "darkred",
               position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, colour = "red", 
               position = position_dodge(width = 0.75),
               geom = "text", vjust = -0.7, 
               aes(label = round(..y.., digits = 1), group = name)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("deepskyblue2", "gold", "gray"), name = "") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "top") +
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  The ggplot version is fine.