# Change mean symbol in boxplot from dot to square (or any other shape) ggboxplot

Tags: r, ggpubr

Currently, I have the mean indicated as a dot within a boxplot using ggboxplot with ggpubr. Is there a way to change the symbol to a square (or a different symbol)? Since I have jitter indicated by dots as well, I'd like it to be less confusing to readers. I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `stat_summary()` like in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64082648/r-how-to-label-means-in-ggboxplot-with-3-variables-and-a-4-level-factor-atte).

```
library(ggpubr)

data(iris)

ggboxplot(iris, x = "Species", y = "Sepal.Length", add = "jitter") +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "point", shape = 15, size = 3, color = "red")
```

[image]